# tor browser in docker, how using with X or Wayland

Tags: browser, docker, anonymous, tor

I need deleting all information of tor browser.
Is possible to creating a docker image with normal browser with tor proxy and using it trought ssh -X options?
Runing it with --rm=true automaic deleting kontainer data and always using this same configuration.
Is possible using this continer in the cloud? For example in AWS ,Azure etc.?

Is possible to download directory mount in my host machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Linux or Mac you can do this.

See item 9 in Jess' blog post: [Docker Containers on the Desktop](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/):

```
docker run -it \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \ # mount the X11 socket
-e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \ # pass the display
--device /dev/snd \ # sound
--name tor-browser \
jess/tor-browser
```

Comment: is possible to add --rm=true in every time i delete container and run from clean image.  Secont trouble is download directory. can You add -v ~/my/directory:/directry/tor/downloads

Comment: this is not normal browser, not have javascript etc.

Comment: How about this (again from Jess): [How to Route Traffic through a Tor Docker container](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/routing-traffic-through-tor-docker-container/)